# Manual way to Automate the verificaton process (i.e for phone(text), voice, etc.) using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a web App which contains `phone/voice verification` in one process flow, I am trying to automate this verification process. My Query is:

Is there any way to do it manually like for example entering phone(text)/voice code manually when occurs, while enter code the thread sleeps or wait 'until ExpectedConditon'? 
For example: we'll do in the case when the page is in processing phase so, we use

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.some selector));
```

it will wait for certain 'timeOutSeconds'.

thanks in advance..........

Comment: From a automation pov, it doesn't make a logical reason that you put a hold on your tests to wait for a manual input. Although you can control the Thread with Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example that i wrote that i'll think it's going to suit your need. In this code the driver starts opening Google. Once the page fully loads the console waits for the input data on the console (i.e. http://www.stackoverflow.com).

This code will probably solve your issue with the manual input during test run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufRead  = new BufferedReader(istream);
    String nextWebSite = "http://www.google.com";

    driver.get(nextWebSite);

    try {
        System.out.println("What's the next Website you'll like to visit? ");
        nextWebSite = bufRead.readLine();
    } catch (IOException err) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there was a problem reading the informed data");
    }

    driver.get(nextWebSite);

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```